# fread to C++ Vecotor

Tags: c++, vector

I have a binary file,

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("file_name.data", "rb");
```

Which can be successfully read using fread() with the following C code

```
int S = 8;
int *table = (int*)malloc(S*sizeof(int));
fread(table, S*sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

But when I read file to C++ vector, the result is wrong

```
vector<int> table;
table.resize(S);
fread(&table[0],table.size(), 1, fp);
```

Is there anything wrong with above  code ?.

Comment: Why are you using `stdio` for C++ code along with `malloc`? Surely `iostreams` and `new` is the order of the day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table.size()` returns the number of elements in the `std::vector`, not the number of bytes. You still need to multiply that by the size of each element, just like you do in the `C` code.

```
fread(&table[0],table.size()*sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

Comment: Debatable, but isn't `table.size() * sizeof(table[0])` a better approach? I know they both accomplish the same thing, but in terms of readability I always find it more readable.

Comment: @Freddy: I agree with you. There are other improvements that can be made as well. See the other answers...

Answer (score 4):

Your `fread` should be:-

```
fread (&table[0], sizeof(vector<int>::value_type), table.size(), fp);
// OR
fread (&table[0], sizeof(int), table.size(), fp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Both appear to be wrong (although the C version looks like it will work).

**See:** http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm

Try these:

```
int S = 8;
int *table = (int*)malloc(S*sizeof(int));
fread(table, sizeof(int), S, fp);

vector<int> table;
table.resize(S);
fread(&table[0], sizeof(int), table.size(), fp);
```